# What Microsoft Azure should i use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cloud, multi-tenant, saas

My company is about provide e-commercial website service and finding the best solution for deployment.

Our application is a multi-tenant e-commercial application. Once purchased, our customer has a website. The newly created website can be browsed by default subdomain on our domain (our domain is invishop.com) eg: mikeshop.invishop.com. The website also can be browsed by customer's custom domain. This requires to create CNAME record to our domain name (invishop.com). Our multi-tenant application  is developed in ASP.NET MVC platform.

The simplest solution our considered is Windows hosting with Dedicated IP but this solution does not meet big users requirement. Our application will be used by up to 1000 or higher at a same time. If we deploy our service on shared ASP.NET hosting our service is always can not access. We want to run our application on higher availability Infrastructure but do not want to focus on building and managing Infrastructure. We only want to focus on develop our application and business.

So what service we should use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Azure virtual machines for hosting. VMs are scalable and you can make availability set with other VMs. So, if is going down (update etc), the second will working. You can create virtual network and assign some VMs to it (Web server and database server). You can use backup services for each VM too.
You can make VM with dedicated IP - Be careful it is possible to configure ONLY before you make VM - you must use PowerShell.

1. - Create dedicated IP via PowerShell (see on internet commands)
2. - Create virtual network (not necessary)
3. - create VM - web server and assign it to IP via PowerShell
4. - create VM - SQL server
5. - Configure server for IIS - it is possible to host multiple websites on one VM via host names (I use this). Add A record to your domain(xyz.com and www.xyz.com and your dedicated IP)